# Write to text file online, What does the web path look like?

Tags: asp.net, path, web-config, log4net

I'm trying to write a log function for my website and am having difficulty writing the logs to the text file. I am using log4net.

I think my problem is with the path. The logger works on my local host when the text file is stored on my PC but the code won't work online.

The text file I'm trying to write to is called `currentLog.txt`, as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

In my web.config I have the option to insert the path in witch to find the text file. I can't seem to find the correct way to insert the path.

```
<file value="../../Logs/CurrentLog.txt"/>
<file value="..\\Logs\\CurrentLog.txt"/>
<file value="~/Logs/CurrentLog.txt"/>
<file value="/formvlgx/formvalue.co.za/wwwroot/Logs/CurrentLog.txt"/>
<file value="http://formvalue.co.za/wwwroot/Logs/CurrentLog.txt"/>
```

Could someone please show me the correct way to insert a path for a live site?

Answer (score 0):

your value should be like this.
value="../Logs/CurrentLog.txt"

Please use Server.MapPath to get the file location.

Comment: Add this code to your web.config file's appSettings section. <add key="ErrorFilePath" value="../Logs/CurrentLog.txt" /> And you can write in code behind like this : HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorFilePath"]))

Comment: Thanks, i cant get it right in my web.config tho, where and how do i write that HttpContext.....

Comment: You can refer this site. [Create Simple Error Log Files using ASP.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2344/Create-Simple-Error-Log-Files-using-ASP-NET-and-C)

Answer (score 0):

Web path would be: http://formvalue.co.za/Logs/CurrentLog.txt

Absolute path on server: /formvlgx/formvalue.co.za/wwwroot/Logs/CurrentLog.txt

Note: Be careful with making logs accessible to the public.